# Print out an iterative array at the end of the iteration in C

Tags: c, arrays, iteration, printf

Perhaps this is a silly question, but in my C code I iterate over a 3X3 array, and I need to print out the final values of that array after the iteration.

My question is: where should I put the command to printf the values in the array? Putting the printf after the array is specified doesn't really make sense to me, and didn't work anyhow.

I am rather new to C, so any help would be greatly appreciated :-D! Thanks!

Comment: You have 2 nested for loops. If you want to print each value, in the second. If you want to print rows, after second. If you want to print total, after first.

Comment: Show the code you made to try to do this.

Comment: Please show the actual code; the `printf` in any case has to be executed after the declaration.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you use 2 nested `for` loops to go through the array.

```
for (/* rows */) {
    for (/* columns */) {
        /* put the printf here for manipulations for individual cells */
    }
    /* put the printf here for manipulations on rows */
}
/* put the printf here for manipulations on the table */
```

Comment: `/* printf here for rows */` doesn't seem correct!!

Comment: I don't know what he wants to do with the code. Could be sum, could be average, or something different. This is pseudo-code to indicate where he can print the appropriate info.

Comment: I agree with you, I just meant it should be something like:  `/*printf here for any specific row */` as you edited it now.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do something like this

```
for(i=0; i<3;i++)
   for(j=0;j<3;j++)
        printf("%d ", array[i][j];
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are dealing with a two dimensional array you might want to have a new line after printing each 3 elements (a single row)

```
for(i=0;i<3;i++)              /* first for() loop*/
{
    for(j=0;j<3;j++)          /* second for() loop*/
    {
        /* Your caculations/operations to be done for each element   */
        printf(" %d ",a[i][j]); /* Print the three elements (assuming an integer array a[3][3] with values stored)  */
    }
    printf("\n");               /* A new line is printed after printing 3 elements   */
}
```